# Reading from a file arrays

Tags: java

I am taking an intro level class on Java and have run into a small issue.  I am reading from a file, with a random number of integers (ex. 2 24 31 4 5 6 7 8 9 11 15) and I must input these integers into an array.

**Assignment**
1)  Write a program that will ask for the user to input a filename of a text file that contains an unknown number of integers. And also an output filename to display results.  You will read all of the integers from the input file, and store them in an array. (You may need to read all the values in the file once just to get the total count)  Using this array you will find the max number, min number, average value, and standard deviation.  These results will be reported to both the screen and placed into the output file that the user choose. 
    Output to screen and file could look like this:

```
    Read from file: 12 values
        Maximum value = 20
    Minimum value = 3
    Average value = 13.34
    Standard Deviation = 2.15
```

You can create a simple NotePad file to store a bunch of integers, just make sure that there is at least a space or a line between each number.

**Problem:** If I don't know how many variables are in the file, how do I know what variable to initialize the array to?  I thought about putting the array initialization below the for loop..but then I wouldn't have the array initialized.

**My code is below:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class lab13
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
   {

   Scanner keyboard= new Scanner (System.in);

   File text = new File("readme.txt"); //creating file readme.txt
   Scanner fromfile = new Scanner(text);  //reading from File txt

   int counter=0;  

      int [] array = new int[10];
      for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
      {            
         array[i] = fromfile.nextInt(); //storing integers into array

         System.out.println(" "+array[i]);   //print out numbers in file
         counter++;
      }

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Read from file:"+counter+" values");        
}
```

**EDIT:** The answer to my problem was to have 2 arrays, one read the file to count the number of variables, and the other array to store the variables.

I am not sure why this was flagged as a "Duplicate" as the other Question is yes reading from a file.  However it is entirely different. Man this Community is harsh. lol.

Comment: Because the size of array would be dynamic, ArrayList would be better solution.

Comment: Hint: you are not limited to using a single array. You need to resize the array as you read the integers.

Comment: Without initially knowing how much data is in the file, there is no way to determine how big the array should be. You'd have to keep adding data to a `List` then convert it to an array, but I'm not sure if that would be acceptable. Your best option: ask your teacher

Comment: @DB And at what rate should the array grow? Is he supposed to trim the array after? Does the rate and trimming matter? The only one who could answer such questions would be the person who gave him the assignment.

Comment: @VinceEmigh since it's an intro class I was thinking a rate of 1, but yes to be certain he should ask the instructor.

Comment: @D.B. Then there's the question of "*what size should th first array be?*" Let's say we assume there must be at least 100 elements, so we do `int[100]` and anytime we reach the end, we create a new array with a size of `length + 1`. Now imagine that there is actually 100k elements in the file: you will be creating 99k+ short-lived objects for the sake of dynamic growth. This is why `ArrayList` avoids that approach to dynamic size.

Comment: @VinceEmigh I agree with everything you said, but that's likely a topic beyond the scope of an intro course. I suggested resizing the array simply because it seems likely the OP has not learned about the collections framework yet and the question specifically said the requirement was to use an array.

Comment: @D.B. I understand, your suggestion is actually the 2nd best way I can think of, next to loading all file data into memory, splitting based on the delimiter, then parsing each value. The only problem with your suggestion is the concept of dynamically growing the array, and what the initial size of the array should be. This is information we can't determine, which is why I refrained from making the suggestion. Honestly, there is no way to determine what his teacher requires, we can only assume /: We need more info, but really, he should let his teacher know he doesn't understand the assignment.

Comment: Thank you for all of your input!!!  

'Vince Emigh', 'D.B.'-My professor does not answer emails.  So that is why I have resorted to stack overflow.  I have edited my post to show my assignment in full so you may better understand my question.

'Luminous_Dev'- I have never used Array List before but I will be looking into it thank you for your input

Answer (score -1):

If the assignment is to strictly use an array you could use a loop to count the number of entries, like this.

```
int num = 0;
while (text.hasNext())
       num++;
```

this will count the number integers in the file. Then you initialize the array with the variable num

Comment: When I try and use the "method.hasNext()" I get the following error message.

lab13.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
while (text.hasNext())
           ^
  symbol:   method hasNext()
  location: variable text of type File
1 error

Not sure how to write a condition that checks each int inside the file.

Comment: Sorry, i messed up. replace text.hasNext() with fromFile.hasNext(). .hasNext() is a Scanner method, not File

Answer (score -1):

you can use an ArrayList. An ArrayList is an object that wraps an array, and handles reallocating a new array when you add elements to it.

Comment: I've never used ArrayList...when l look up examples..it all seems like words I've never learned or used before.